# How would a socirity works with many different species?

Tags: society, conflict

the world my sister and I are making, there exist four "head" species, which is Humanlin, Dragons and Demons.

I was wondering how you would make a society with very different species, which all have their own tradition and mannerism function in relative harmony?

a few small notes about each species:

humanlins are incredible builders but due to shorter lifespan, they are quicker to action and thus often viewed as impatient. they were the first to use magic.

Dragons are a proud species and can be considered arrogant in how they view themselves. they come in all sizes (from as small as a pony to as big as a mammoth) and when enraged, they will breathe fire.
dragons were the first to invent written words and loves to hear a good story.

Demons is kinda an odd one, for although they like a good fight, they don't care much about war. like dragons, they come in all sizes but also in many forms due to their unique traits to get offspring with pretty much anything that breathes. their lax attitude on things can be infuriating with other species.
the demons introduced a very lax view on sexuality.

I will answer if you have more questions.

Comment: I think your sister posted the very same question not too long ago and it got closed. Please improve it, just insisting with the same question won't bring you anywhere.

Comment: *"There exist four "head" species, which is Humanlin, Dragons and Demons":* there exist four head species, names species 1, species 2 and species 3. And I have the same comment as I had for [@FableSisters' question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/189181): it worked for Homer, it worked for Rabelais, it worked for countless fairy tales: what is it that makes your story so special that you need to nail down the hows and whys? There are f̶o̶u̶r three main species, and that's how many there are. It's not as if you are making impossible associations, as in *Zootopia*.

Comment: What is a Sorcirity?